# BASH - how echo works inside EOF tags

Tags: bash

I would like to execute the followings:

```
PASSWORD="mypassword"
RUNCOMMAND=$(cat <<EOF
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S sudo echo "this is it babe"
EOF
)
```

But instead of `this is it babe`, I get the following result:

```
mypassword | sudo -S sudo echo "this is it babe"
```

I tried with `cat <<\EOF`, `cat <<'EOF'` still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that you have lost the forest while looking for the trees here? It seems to me that your actual problem is rather simple. In any case, code inside a heredoc block is not executed. That's the point. If you want it to execute, just write it as normal code.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing a `heredoc` with a `pipeline`.

## heredoc with variable expansion:

```sh
cat <<EOF
some text, possibly with variables: ${HOME} / $(whoami)
EOF
```

```
some text, possibly with variables: /home/attie / attie
```

## heredoc without variable expansion:

```sh
cat <<"EOF"
some text, possibly with variables: ${HOME} / $(whoami)
EOF
```

```
some text, possibly with variables: ${HOME} / $(whoami)
```

## pipeline with variable expansion (note the quotes, `"`):

```sh
echo "some text, possibly with variables: ${HOME} / $(whoami)" | cat
```

```
some text, possibly with variables: /home/attie / attie
```

## pipeline without variable expansion (note the quotes, `'`):

```sh
echo 'some text, possibly with variables: ${HOME} / $(whoami)' | cat
```

```
some text, possibly with variables: ${HOME} / $(whoami)
```

---

`${...}` expands an environment variable

`$(...)` runs a command, and substitutes its `stdout`

---

It also looks like you're trying to have your password entered into `sudo` - this won't work, as sudo will repoen the terminal to acquire your password, before passing it's `stdin` to the final application.

Comment: `sudo -S` gets the password from stdin. The original example works, if you simply paste into the terminal. In the meantime I found the solution, although thank you for your time, really appreciated.

Comment: ah, yes. apologies

Answer (score 1):

You are starting from a false premise, that `eval $RUNCOMMAND` is something you should do. It is not; variables are for data, *functions* are for code.

```
run_command () {
    docker_run_options=(
       --restart=always
       --name "${USER_NAME}_$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
       -d
       -e "VIRTUAL_HOST=$USER_VIRTUAL_HOST"
       -e "VIRTUAL_PORT=$USER_VIRTUAL_PORT"
       -e "PORT=$USER_VIRTUAL_PORT"
       -p "$USER_VIRTUAL_PORT:$USER_VIRTUAL_PORT"
    )

    echo "$1" | sudo -S sudo docker run "${docker_run_options[@]}" "$USER_IMAGE"
}

fun_run_command () {
    run_command "PASSWORD"
}
```

Comment: the whole point is, to be able simply echo the command, what will be executed. So putting together the command into a variable, and use a function (`fun_echo_command`) which echoes it to stdout, and use an another function (`fun_run_command`) which executes it. Those function are general enough to live in an external file (in my case is `common/variables.sh`), which I include in my scripts. I don't see how could you achieve echoing before executing, without copying commands over to the other function.

Comment: The security implication of `eval` is rather moot in this case. Since the script is asking for *user input*, so if the user wants to write malice code into one of the variables, he can do so in the terminal (without the script) in the first place. Still I don't see how could you `echo` the command what will be executed first. (that is my goal)

Answer (score -1):

The final solution is rather simple:

```
PASSWORD="mypassword"
RUNCOMMAND=$(cat <<EOF
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S sudo echo "this is it babe"
EOF
)
```

And execute it via `eval`:

```
eval $RUNCOMMAND
```

Sorry for stealing your times with this obvious problem guys:)

The usecase for the above is to `echo` a given command before really executing it.

Like this:

```
fun_run_command(){
# execute the final command
echo `eval $RUNCOMMAND`
}

fun_echo_command(){
# echo the command which will be launched (fun_run_command())
echo ${RUNCOMMAND//$PASSWORD/PASSWORD}
}

RUNCOMMAND=$(cat <<EOF
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S sudo docker run --restart=always \
--name ${USER_NAME}_`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S` \
-d \
-e "VIRTUAL_HOST=$USER_VIRTUAL_HOST" \
-e "VIRTUAL_PORT=$USER_VIRTUAL_PORT" \
-e "PORT=$USER_VIRTUAL_PORT" \
-p $USER_VIRTUAL_PORT:$USER_VIRTUAL_PORT \
$USER_IMAGE
EOF
)
```

As you can see the command what I launch is quite long, 
so it is always make sense to doublecheck what is executed by the script.

Having copy&paste the same command to multiple function is prone to error.